# Understanding a paragraph (from upper level ISEE Prep guide)

Tags: comprehension

My son is going through the "Upper Level ISEE Prep Guide" (3rd edition). The first paragraph of a **Reading Comprehension** assignment goes like this  (Passage 5, page 188):

> The recently established chair in the history, literature, and
> institutions of the United States which is to be shared among the
> several universities of Great Britain, is quite different from the
> exchange professorships of sometimes unhappy memory. It is not at all
> the idea to carry over one of our professors each year and
> indoctrinate him with the true culture at its source. The occupant of
> the chair will be, if the announced intention is carried out, quite as
> often British as American, and quite as likely a public man as a
> professor. The chief object is to bring to England a better knowledge
> of the United States, and a purpose more laudable can scarcely be
> imagined. Peace and prosperity will endure in the world in some very
> precise relation to the extent to which England succeeds in
> understanding us.

Question: Which of the following is the least likely to chair the department of history, literature, and institutions of the United States?

A. American professor

B. American public figure

C. British professor

D. British public figure.

Our thinking (pause a second, what's your answer? then click to unmask ours):

> Our answer is D. Our reasoning is simply that a British public figure may know absolutely nothing of the United States and be of no use as chair, while a British professor might qualify if they specialize in an appropriate subject (e.g. American literature), while American professors and American public figures are likely to be knowledgeable in some way about America and therefore be of some use as chair. The "correct" answer is apparently A.

From the context of the other paragraphs and the style, this text is clearly from the nineteenth century.

Comment: I'm hiding our answer and the reasoning on purpose. :-)

Comment: Why? This isn't Puzzling, you need to openly detail your research. Hiding it makes no sense at all.

Comment: Hopefully you'll accept my choice here. Hopefully it's not violating rules? I want people to be able to pause and think about what their answer would be before seeing the "official" answer and our reasoning. It helps to hide it. The "research" as you call it is a tiny click away. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I would have chosen A. but with considerable hesitation, because it says the chosen candidate will be _as likely_ British as American (not _more likely_) and as likely a public man as a professor.

Comment: There's no harm whatsoever in keeping the spoiler. It's adding elements of suspense, curiosity and fun while clicking on the "answer" is as easy as ABC. As for the answer, I was undecided between two options, and neither was correct!

Comment: @KateBunting, what is your reasoning for picking A? Is it the sentence "It is not at all the idea to carry over one of our professors" ? The part that says "equally likely" says that A+B is as likely as C+D (American vs British) and that A+C is as likely as B+D (Professor vs Public man). Other than that it doesn't help. So I guess it's down to that one sentence about "not carrying over one of our professors"?

Comment: Yes, I suppose so. As I said, I chose that answer with hesitation; my interpretation of the passage would be 'They are all equally likely'.

Comment: Thanks Kate. You could put that down as an answer if you wanted to!

Comment: Very open-minded approach to filling a position--as long as you're a guy. I vote with @KateBunting

Comment: Any (official or practice) standardized test on reading comprehension will have a small handful of poorly or misleadingly written questions. The UISEE is no different in this respect, although this one strikes me as particularly egregious given that (as @KateBunting already pointed out) the most literal reading of the passage is that answer choices A-D are all equally likely. But it may be some consolation to remember that the UISEE is curved, with the scores more or less reported by/as deciles, so probably a bad question like this is affecting everyone pretty evenly across the board.

Comment: All answers are equal by definition: "Quite as often British as American, and quite as likely a public man as a professor." A small point: Explaining your reasoning does not equal research from respected sources.  But I accept that the mask added fun.

Comment: Not all answers are equal by definition: You are neglecting potential correlation across outcomes. What we know is A+B is as likely as C+D; and A+C is as likely as B+D. We do not know that A,B,C,D are equally likely. If they were, the question would be nonsensical. Our reasoning was that, on average, an American would know more about America than a Brit; a professor would be more knowledgeable about America than a public person. But the suggested answer contradicts this common sense reasoning. Thus "It is not at all the idea to carry over one of our professors" is probably all there is to it.

Comment: Would someone like to answer this question so we can put the matter to rest? :-)